# PHP5.3.8 Interactive Shell does not initiate PROMPT> when run in Windows 7 / Windows 2k8

Tags: php, command-line-interface

has anyone had an issue on the prompt not initializing with the Interactive mode?

PHP 5.3.8 when running the cmd php -a seems to just hang.

I have tested the php.exe with and without out php.ini and still get the same result.  I have also tested on two different machines.  Both fail to give my a prompt.

If you know what I am missing please let me know

Screen shot below

Thanks!

Comment: I fought with PHP on windows for a long time before throwing up my hands and using a Linux dev box. My experience is that it **just works** without issue on Linux while Windows can trip over a million different issues.

Comment: yes I recently came to the same conclusion.

Comment: I am facing the same. According to https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs, the readline library is not available for windows. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Just some more info for anyone who winds up here, there's some discussion about this on php.net. Search for "windows" with ctrl+f on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `php -a` doesn't provide a prompt like it does on Linux. But the interactive mode is still working, you just have to write a "complete" script including the `<?php` start tag and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
C:\>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo 5+3;
^Z
8
C:\>
```

Comment: This prints `echo 5+3;` for me, not `8`

Comment: @CurvianVynes Did you enter `<?php` as well? That's what I meant with 'you just have to write a "complete" script'.

Comment: Oh geez I'm sorry, no I did not. I keep thinking in terms of interactive shell on linux. Thanks.

Comment: It works but with a funky message: <?php
echo 5+3;
?>
^Z
8Ran out of opcode space!
You should probably consider writing this huge script into a file!